# Multiple criteria in a filter/summation combined, entered into two columns for sorting

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that tallies sales over time, including sales person, office they work out of, and the price of whatever it is that they sold. I am attempting to create a two-column filtered list by multiple criteria. The data looks like this:

```
Date         Name             Office           Price
5/5/12       Joe              OW               220000
6/1/12       Jim              SOL              100000
```

What I want to be able to do is create a two-column entry that sums the price column, but uses multiple critera from the first three to do so. For instance, "everyone named Jim who sold something in May", and then I'd like to sort that by the top three.

Using items like:

```
=FILTER( C1:C ; D1:D="OW"; month(B1:B)=month("5/12/12"))
```

and

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(frequency(MATCH(E1:E&counta(E1:E),UNIQUE(E1:E&counta(E1:E)),0), MATCH(UNIQUE(E1:E&counta(E1:E)),UNIQUE(E1:E&counta(E1:E)),0)))
```

I can filter and tally, but I am unable to replace the frequency mentioned above with a summation of the price column.

Comment: are you after an excel formula, or a google spreadsheet formula?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using FILTER you could put together something using SUMPRODUCT:

```
=arrayformula(sumproduct($E$2:$E$3*($C$2:$C$3=C2)))
```

If you have column E as price and column C as name, this creates a new column that shows the total earnings for each name, next to every instance where that name appears in the array. You can apply further conditions within the SUMPRODUCT call as needed. You could then apply UNIQUE to deduplicate and sort the resulting table to see the top 3.